# How would you display the interval of notation of a series if it a single value?

Tags: calculus, notation

[image: Math question]

So I have the radius of convergence and I'm pretty sure that $x = \frac{1}{4}$ for the interval of convergence, I only have one attempt left and I've tried inputting $\frac{1}{4}$, $[\frac{1}{4}]$, $\{\frac{1}{4}\}$, and simply $x = \frac{1}{4}$. I'm not really sure how else I can express the answer, so I want to try $[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}]$. Does that seem correct? Or do I just have the wrong interval altogether?

Comment: Seems reasonable enough; they are asking for interval notation, even if this one is somewhat of a degenerate case.

Comment: AFAIK interval notation refers to $(a, b)$, $[a, b]$, $[a, b)$ or $(a, b]$. Since $a$ and $b$ can be any real numbers, $[1, 0]$, (0, 0) and $[0, 0]$ are perfectly fine interval notations.